# How to handle MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE in multiple CustomViews?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java and android development and I want to create this basic app, which consists of multiple CustomViews, where I could move different shapes drawn on canvas.
My idea is to have one class that handles MotionEvents and passes them to individual CustomViews.

My CustomView class:

```
public class CustomView extends View implements MoveDetector.OnMoveListener {
private MoveDetector mMoveDetector;

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(attrs);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(attrs);
}
private void init(@Nullable AttributeSet set){
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#626696"));
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mMoveDetector = new MoveDetector(this);
            mMoveDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            float cx = mMoveDetector.getCx();
            float cy = mMoveDetector.getCy();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"why u packin heat bro?"+Float.toString(cx)+"    "+Float.toString(cy),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Moveee", "Move: " + Float.toString(cx)+"    " + Float.toString(cy));
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void OnMove(MoveDetector moveDetector) {
}
}
```

My MoveDetector Class:

```
public class MoveDetector {
private float cx,cy, mCislo1,mCislo2;

public float getCx() {
    return mCislo1;
}

public float getCy() {
    return mCislo2;
}

private OnMoveListener mListener;

public MoveDetector(OnMoveListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            mCislo1 = cXX(x);
            mCislo2 = cYY(y);

            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.OnMove(this);
            }

            break;
    }
return true;}
public static interface OnMoveListener {
    public void OnMove(MoveDetector moveDetector);
}
public float cXX(float x){
    cx = x;
    return cx;
}
public float cYY(float y){
    cy = y;
    return cy;
}
}
```

It doesn't seem to be working and I can't point why.
I searched a solution for ages and couldn't find any.
So I'd be really thankful if someone could help me out.
P.S.: Sorry, if my code is messy: I'm still learning.

Comment: just pass view as second param and compare id of view
 public void OnMove(MoveDetector moveDetector, View v){}

Comment: How do i compare an id of CustomView? I guess this is supposed to be basic stuff, but i really dont know.